# Why do I get a jitter/stutter when moving and following a target?

Tags: unity, c#, movement, transformation

I am using the script below to move a transform to quickly follow a target (the player), and come to a stop close to the player.

When I move the player around, the transform is following the player, keeping the 1.5 distance.

To ensure the transform can keep up with the player, I set the `moveSpeed` to 5, But when I do that, the transform jitters/stutters when moving.

If I set the `moveSpeed` to 1 for example, the transform will move smoothly but will not keep up with the player - the player has to stop moving and wait for it to catch up. But increasing the speed makes the stutter return.

Why is this stutter happening, and how can I make the movement smooth?

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Follow : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform targetToFollow;
    public Text text;
    public Text text1;
    public float lookAtRotationSpeed;
    public float moveSpeed;

    private float minMoveSpeed = 0f;
    private Vector3 originPos;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        originPos = targetToFollow.position;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 lTargetDir = targetToFollow.position - transform.position;
        lTargetDir.y = 0.0f;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation,
            Quaternion.LookRotation(lTargetDir), Time.time * lookAtRotationSpeed);

        var distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, targetToFollow.position);

        text.text = "Transform Distance From Target " + distance.ToString();

        float ms = moveSpeed;

        if (distance > 5f)
        {
            ms = moveSpeed + 0.5f;
        }
        else if (distance < 1.5f)
        {
            ms = Mathf.Max(minMoveSpeed, ms - 0.3f);
        }
        else
        {
            //transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetToFollow.position, Time.deltaTime * ms);
        }

        if (distance < 0.5f && originPos == targetToFollow.position)
        {
            ms = 0f;
        }

        if (distance > 1.5f)
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetToFollow.position, Time.deltaTime * ms);

        originPos = targetToFollow.position;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two hard cutoffs in your code:

```
if (distance > 5f)
{
    ms = moveSpeed + 0.5f;
}
```

This switches to a higher seed if the object is more than 5 units away.

```
if (distance > 1.5f)
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetToFollow.position, Time.deltaTime * ms);
```

This moves the object only if the object is more than 1.5 units away.

Consider what happens when your distance is *close* to one of these thresholds.

- On frame 1, I'm 1.51 units away.

  That's more than 1.5, so **I take a step** of .16 units, now I'm 1.34 units away
- On frame 2, my target has moved .1 units further away, so now I'm 1.44 units from it.

  That's less than 1.5, so **I don't move**.
- On frame 3, my target has moved .1 units again, so now I'm 1.54 units from it.

  That's more than 1.5, so **I take a step** of .16 units, now I'm 1.38 units away.
- On frame 5, my target has moved .1 units again, so now I'm 1.48 units from it.

  That's less than 1.5, so **I don't move**.

You can see, instead of approaching at a slow rate to keep pace with the object I'm following, I stop and start. On alternating frames I find myself too far (so I move and overshoot) or too close (so I stop), creating a jerky, stuttering movement.

The same thing can happen more subtly at the 5 unit cutoff, where I alternate between taking big steps (because I'm just past 5 units) and small steps (because I'm just under 5 units).

You can solve the hard movement cutoff by aiming for the place where you would want to stop. That way you take a smaller move when you're very close, rather than overshooting.

```
float followRadius = 1.5f;

// Compute a position no further than followRadius away from our target.
Vector3 fromTarget = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(-lTargetDir.normalized, followRadius);    
Vector3 stopPoint = targetToFollow.position + fromTarget;

// Move as far as we can at our speed ms to reach the stopPoint, without overshooting.
transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, stopPoint, Time.deltaTime * ms);
```

To solve the sharp speed change you get at the 5 unit mark, you can blend the speed gradually over a longer distance, something like...

```
float fastRadius = 5f;
float speedBoost = 0.5f;

float speedBlend= Mathf.Clamp01((distance - followRadius)/(fastRadius-followRadius));

ms = moveSpeed + speedBlend * speedBoost;
```

This has you moving at your normal move speed when close to the `followRadius`, and at your faster speed when at/beyond your `fastRadius`, with a smooth acceleration/deceleration in between.

Comment: Yes I see the hard cutoffs there. When I'm using your solution instead my code the transform is not staying close to the player when the player is moving. The transform move but the player is moving faster so the distance get bigger and I need to stop moving the player and waiting to the transform to get closer.  In my code the transform is staying close to the player by 1.5 when moving the player. Should I keep my code and add to it your solution ?

Comment: You can increase the `moveSpeed` or `speedBoost` variables if the transform is not moving fast enough for your needs.

Comment: I tried it again and it stutter again. but when I changed the function from Update to FixedUpdate it's working smooth now.  Could be the problem is that the target the player that I move have a Rigidbody component ? Not the transform in the Follow script but the targetToFollow have a Rigidbody.

Comment: Yes, because FixedUpdate and physics tick at a different interval than the Update function, leading to judder between the two. Don't forget to include important details like that in your question!

Comment: I will include this detail/s next time. Thank you very much.

Comment: You may also want to consider enabling Interpolation on your player object, so you get smooth movement even on update frames between physics steps

Comment: How can I add a slowdown when running the game the transform is far from the target and maybe in other places in the game the transform might be far from the target doing some tasks missions and then moving back to the target in this cases I want to make the transform to slow down a bit when it's getting close to the target. Now it's just stopping at once. I think it will be nicer if it will be slow down a bit when the transform is coming from a far distance.

Comment: Something like this logic I think : if(distance > followRadius && distance < fastRadius)

Comment: The last code sample in the answer shows you how to ramp the speed from a higher value to a lower value based on distance.

Comment: but this line moveSpeed += speedBlend * speedBoost; will make the transform move faster.  I didn't understand how to use the last code in the answer for slow down.

Comment: Make speedBoost negative to slow down when speedBlend is high. Or reduce your moveSpeed to a lower value to control how fast you move when speedBlend is zero. I will not reply here again, but you can create a new Question post if you need further assistance.